# Modifying a constant for a Subclass

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby, so excuse the likely noob question, but Google has been unhelpful on this so far.

I have a class constant defined in my parent class

```
Items = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

And then I have a subclass where I want to add an array [1, 5, 9] into the Items array. Can you reference super / redefine the constant in such a way?

Something like

```
Items = super.Items.concat([1, 5, 9])
```

I would like to not need to copy the Items definition into my subclass with the additional item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constants are name spaced within the class or module they are defined. They are resolved through the usual ancestors path.  In your subclass you can define a constant of the same name as one in the superclass, and the expression initializing it can reference the superclass's constant as the subclass's constant won't be defined until after the initial assignment. Like this:

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> class A; Items = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]; end
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
[2] pry(main)> class B < A; end
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> class B; Items; end
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
[4] pry(main)> A::Items
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
[5] pry(main)> B::Items
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
[6] pry(main)> class B; Items = Items.dup << [7,8,9]; end
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[7] pry(main)> A::Items
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
[8] pry(main)> B::Items
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

When deriving the new constant, be careful to `dup` the original if you plan to modify it with a mutating method (like [`Array#<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C)). See the trap:

```
[9] pry(main)> class A; Foo = [[1,2],[3,4]]; end
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[10] pry(main)> A::Foo
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[11] pry(main)> class B; Foo = Foo << [5,6]; end
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[12] pry(main)> B::Foo
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[13] pry(main)> A::Foo
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[14] pry(main)> B::Foo.object_id == A::Foo.object_id
=> true
[15] pry(main)> B::Items.object_id == A::Items.object_id
=> false
```

You can explicitly reference the constant in the parent namespace without naming the superclass using [`Class#superclass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass)

```
[16] pry(main)> class B; superclass::Items; end
=> [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you link to the documentation for <<? Google doesn't like it as a keyword. I had trouble using that, but when replaced with .concat, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Constant lookup is not always super obvious in Ruby, in particular because it is usually not scoped (e.g. we write `String`, not `::String`)

You can override it in subclasses. You can build on it by accessing the [`superclass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass):

```
class C < Base
  CONST = build_on(superclass::CONST)
end
```

You have to be careful as to how you access the constant from instance and singleton methods though:

```
class Base
  FOO = [42]

  def self.naive
    FOO
  end

  def naive_ins
    FOO
  end

  def self.aware
    self::FOO
  end

  def aware_ins
    self.class::FOO
  end
end

class C < Base
  FOO = superclass::FOO + [:bar]
end

C.naive # => [42]
C.new.naive_ins # => [42]
C.aware # => [42, :bar]
C.new.aware_ins # => [42, :bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

Constants are scoped to the class they are defined. So you can redefine the constant in the subclass if you want.

Comment: I'd like to not have to redefine the whole thing (copying and pasting) I guess I am ideally looking for something like Items = super.Items.concat([1, 5, 9]), where I only have to define my new items, and not the ones that the super class defined.